# What sense could it make not to close an InputStream after it ended?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

`InputStream` implements `Closeable`.

I understand, that closing an InputStream **which not ended yet**, could make sense to free some underlying resources, and, leaving it open, could make sense to let other methods continue to read from it.

But, what sense could it have **not** to close an InputStream **after it ended**?
And if it doesn't make sense, why reaching the end of an InpuntStream does not imply closing then?

*Same question would apply to `Reader`.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mark()` and `reset()` allow you to "go back" in some implementations of the interface.

This is useful when implementing parsers and matching regexps as you usually want to [lookahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookahead).

Comment: My question was about InputStream (and Reader), not Closeable in general. I'm mot aware of rewindable InputStreams or Readers.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's about mark and reset, I forgot they're methods of InputStream / Reader.

Comment: So, that **is** indeed a good reason which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, yes. I was thinking `InputStream` was an interface instead of an  abstract class.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it is quite resasonable to expect `FileInputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream` and `StringReader` to support `mark()` and `reset()`

Answer (score 4):

In response to your comment to org.life.java

> I know, and the question was: why an
>   end of an InputStream does not imply
>   close()?

Because, for some streams, you can rewind them and start reading again.  For others, e.g. Sockets, it's not possible, but they have to obey the contract rules.

Also, because that's how you should close stream ( exception handling not shown ):

```
InputStream stream = openMethod( );

try
{
   consumeMethod( stream );
}
finally
{
   stream.close( );
}
```

In other words, you should release acquired resources regardless whether you totally consumed the stream or not.

Comment: Do you mean, there are subclasses of `Inputstream` or `Reader` which can be rewound?

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop.  Yes, if `markSupported` returns true, then you can `mark` and `reset` stream position.  gpeche put it in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

A reason under Windows could be to keep the file locked.  Open files cannot be renamed, deleted or moved.

Comment: Well, this reason makes sense! Sadly, that it isn't documented in Javadoc.

Comment: This is platform dependent behaviour.  You don't want to do things like that unless you know exactly what you are doing, since this paradigm will break on Unix platforms.

Comment: It cannot/should not be documented in Javadoc, because it is platform-specific (only works that way in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can `mark()` and `reset()` an InputStream.  Therefore, once you reach the end of the data, you can still return to the position that you marked.  Someone who wants to `reset()` an InputStream might not want it to close at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle use case for not closing an input stream after it ends: wrapped streams. By default, closing the wrapper (like FilterInputStream) will close the underlying stream. Sometimes you want to stop using a wrapper but continue using the underlying stream, so you have to simply discard the wrapper without calling close.

Consider this example:

```
try (InputStream in0 = new FileInputStream(...)) {
    int len = (...);
    // Hypothetical class `BoundedInputStream`
    InputStream in1 = new BoundedInputStream(in0, len);
    while (in1.read() != -1);  // Discard bytes until end
    // Now stop using in1 without calling close(),
    // because in1.close() would trigger in0.close()
    
    // Read more data in a different way
    DataInput in2 = new DataInputStream(in0);
    long x = in1.readLong();  // Reads exactly 8 bytes
    // We can neglect in2 without calling close() because
    // itself doesn't hold any limited resources like file handles
    
    // Read more data in a different way
    CheckedInputStream in3 = new CheckedInputStream(in0);
    (...)
    
    // Ultimately call in0.close() directly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the semantics connected with InputStream in java, but in general, you might not close a stream because you didn't open it yourself and just did work on it, and rely on the calling party (another method) to close the stream. If you opened the stream yourself, you shoudl always close it.

Comment: Good, but are there any reasons for the Java API not to close an InputStream after it ended? (Thus implying close on end, which wouldn't be much that problem as far I understand)

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly closing would not be so good, because

- it would only be done when the stream has reached its end, which may not be the case always (some exceptions occur on the way, or you only read the first bytes of a file), so you have to handle these other cases anyway. Having an implicit close that almost always works makes people even more forgetful about their finally blocks.
- some streams can be rewound (mark/reset).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from InputStream's API, there is no problem for a particular implementation to do that, i.e. close upon end of stream. It is probably a very good idea for a lot of streams.